# List and Dictionary Output mismatch for the same Input in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have the following function which makes use of a dictionary of cycle_times to generate lists and dictionaries containing elements whose values are greater than a certain threshold.

```
def anamolous_cycle_time_index_and_lengths(cycle_time_dict, anamoly_threshold):
    for meter,cycle_time_list in cycle_time_dict.items():
        anamoly_dict = {cycle_time_list.index(x):x for x in cycle_time_list if x > anamoly_threshold}
        anamoly_list = [x for x in cycle_time_list if x > anamoly_threshold]
        print(meter,len(anamoly_dict))
        print([value for key,value in anamoly_dict.items()])
        print(anamoly_list)
```

Suppose I give the inputs as

```
new_dict = {104:[2,3,4,5,6,7,3,2,5,6,7], 101:[2,45,4,2,5,2,34,2,5,6,7], 106:[2,23,4,5,65,7,3,23,5,6,7]}
anamoly_threshold = 3
```

The outputs I get are

```
104 4
[4, 5, 6, 7]
[4, 5, 6, 7, 5, 6, 7]
101 6
[45, 4, 5, 34, 6, 7]
[45, 4, 5, 34, 5, 6, 7]
106 6
[23, 4, 5, 65, 7, 6]
[23, 4, 5, 65, 7, 23, 5, 6, 7]
```

Shouldn't the list and dictionary give me the same output? I have run a comprehension for both data structures on the same data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the use of [`.index(x)`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html). This returns the index for the first occurrence of `x`. And since dictionary keys are unique, you will see only the first occurrence of duplicate elements in your dict comprehension.
There are several ways to overcome this problem. The easiest is to use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
anamoly_dict = {index: x for index, x in enumerate(cycle_time_list) if x > anamoly_threshold}
```

Now the output for both methods is the same.